# Using text field input to execute global functions in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am creating a dead simple, one line code editor. The following code enables the user to invoke the `hello` function by typing `parent.hello()`. This is functionally what I had anticipated, yet having to type "parent" before every function is bad UX.

Is there a way to destructure the window object, or selectively expose global functions, in order for the user to simply invoke `hello()`, instead of having to repeatedly call the window object first?

```html
<input type="text" id="editor"/>
<iframe id="window"></iframe>
```

```js
const editor = document.getElementById("editor")
const iframe = document.getElementById("window").contentWindow.document;

window.hello = function () {
    alert("Heya")
};

editor.oninput = function (e) {
    iframe.open();
    iframe.write(`\<script>${e.target.value}\<\/script>`);
    iframe.close();
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way BUT you can re-create `hello` method from within the iframe's js like `function hello(){parent.hello();}` so a user doesn't have to type parent.

Comment: Hi Kubwimana, that's a smart work around. I wonder if there is a cleaner way all-together, though. Previously, I've been working with the `exec` function and directly passing the text input, but this is probably a bad idea security wise.